# how to remove characters after digits in snowflake

Tags: regexp-replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string like this '22-ABCD-BC-220602-11484-TEST' and I want to remove the word 'TEST' from end of this string.
The point is 'TEST' changes each time and is not a constant variable. so what I want to do is writes query to remove what ever comes after digits at the end of string.
like in this case I want it to remove whatever comes after 220602-11484.

I used this query

> select REGEXP_REPLACE('22-ABCD-BC-220602-11484-TEST','([0-9]{6}-[0-9]{5}).*$','')

to replace the end part with space, but the result I get is **'22-ABCD-BC-'** and it removes the digits as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select left('22-ABCD-BC-220602-11484-TEST', len('22-ABCD-BC-220602-11484-TEST') - charindex('-', reverse('22-ABCD-BC-220602-11484-TEST')));
```

We are basically taking in account everything left before that last hyphen.

Reference DOC:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/left.html
  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/reverse.html
  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/charindex.html